# To count the number of controls and print their Id into an alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

To count the number of contols and print their Id into an alert box
I need help with my code

I am trying to count the number of contols in my webpage and display onto the alert box 
Example

```
Textbox: 2 
Buttons: 3
Radio buttons: 5
Drop down:3
Listbox: 1
```

I have used `getElementsByTagName("INPUT")` and  `getElementsByTagName("SELECT")`. For the input fields I have no problem, but for the `select` I have to differentiate between for example drop down list or list box and more

i have tried this for listbox but it isnt working

```
        var search_term = "lst"; // search term
        var search = new RegExp(search_term, "i");
        var arr = jQuery.grep(y, function (value) {
            return search.test(value);
        });
```

And secondly after using getElementsByTagName("INPUT")  I filter again on type(text,checkbox,radio) I want to extract the Id and push it onto an array

Comment: Are you able to provide some examples of your code?

Comment: what is listbox in your terminology? and how is it different from dropdown list?

Comment: dropdown is ddl and listbox is lst ...terminology

Comment: @OliverRadini yes if i have two drop down and one list box .. i store the same in an array arr=document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT") . my arr contains 3 element that is two dropdown and list box  now i want to cout each , so  for dropdown my id will start with ddl and for listbox by id will start with lst , and put it in separate arrays

Answer (score -1):

You can use querySelectorAll method instead of getElementByTag name and use CSS selectors for selecting elements. for example Using

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')
```

selects all of inputs with type="text" and so on

You can get classes of a DOM element by `classList` method and `id` for getting ids

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#foo')[0].id); // prints foo
```

and

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#foo')[0].classList); // prints list of element possible classes
```

Comment: thank you for the reply,, however i want to put the ID of all text boxes into an array and then i want to print them all into a alert box

Comment: i have tried the same . getting an error cannot find property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @roopeshrajug before getting id, make sure that element exists (querrySelector resturns something.)

Comment: ,
Yes the element exits and are stored in an array 
Example arr= document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
Now I want all the textbox IDs in anther array arr_tb[]
for (var cnt = 0; cnt < x.length; cnt++) {
                if (x[cnt].type == "text"||x[cnt].type == "password")
now I want to get he ID